# a noun meaning: “not received”

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I want to write:

> Please ignore the message stating—*noun form of not received*—of the mail.

What is a single word for the noun form of "not received"?

Comment: I believe she's looking for the antonym for **reception**

Comment: Or rather, the noun form for *unreceived*

Answer (score 3):

"Non-delivery" means that the item wasn't delivered.

**Nonreceipt** means that it wasn't received, which seems to be what the question wants.

I was surprised to find the word unhyphenated, but here it is in *[Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nonreceipt)*:

> **nonreceipt** (ˌnɒnrɪˈsiːt)  Definitions noun formal) failure to receive something   ⇒ "This can prove quite helpful in settling
>   disputes with firms that claim nonreceipt of payment."